# Symfony2: Getting the "username" after an unsuccessful login attempt

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, brute-force

I use Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle.

I want to prevent brute force attacks on the login page.

For this I created a listener on the event:

```
AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE
```

Besides the IP I'd like to get also the "username" that the user passed when trying to log. This way I can get the user who some hacker is trying to hack the account. Also considering that the same IP can belong to multiple users, I can this way discriminate, if I get 5 attempts in a second, if I'm really facing an attack or simply there are 5 users that roughly at the same time fail to authenticate (but maybe "behind" that address there are 150 users, so it can happen ;) ).

Is there any way I can get the username passed in the form?

Of course, after the logging of the IP, username and timestamp, I need to implement the part where I add the suspicious IP to a blacklist table. Then I'll have to decide if implementing a Voter, or banning the IP my making my application write the Apache configuration file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I surprisingly found the solution digging a bit on the classes around what I'm doing.

I simply have to do:

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure( AuthenticationFailureEvent $event )
{
   $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken(); 
   $username = $token->getUsername(); 
   // DO STUFF ON DB
}
```

**EDIT**: Full code of my listener as requested

```
class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
protected $entityManager;
protected $container;
protected $logger;

public function __construct($entityManager, $container, $logger)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;        
    $this->container = $container;        
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onImplicitLogin',
        SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE => 'onAuthenticationFailure',
    );
}
public function onImplicitLogin(UserEvent $event)
{
    // LOG THE SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $this->writeSuccessfulLog($user); 

}
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    // LOG THE SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
   $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser(); // the difference with the one above is        $user = $event->getUser();
   $this->writeSuccessfulLog($user);
}

public function onAuthenticationFailure( AuthenticationFailureEvent $event )
{
    // LOG THE FAILED LOGIN
    $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken(); 
    $username = $token->getUsername();  
    $container = $this->container;
    $em = $this->em;
    $request = $container->get('request');
    $ip = $request->getClientIp();
    $userAgent = $request->headers->get('User-Agent');
    $now = new \DateTime();

    $failedLogin = new FailedLogin();
    $failedLogin->setIp($ip);
    $failedLogin->setTimestamp($now);
    $failedLogin->setUsername($username);
    $failedLogin->setUserAgent($userAgent);
    $em->persist($failedLogin);
    $em->flush();
}
```

the method writeSuccessfulLog simply logs on DB

Comment: I am facing the same issue, as you are one of the first result in google, could you please develop a bit your solution ?

Comment: There you go @BastienSander ;)